# C++ : the values of class members are shown 0 on console instead of actual values

Tags: c++, class, oop

i have used constructor to initialize the values and asked user to input the length and width, but when i cout those values it keep showing 0 instead of real values. i couldnot find anything wrong about the code. can anyone help me? i have exam in 2 days.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class rectangle
{
     int width;
     int length;
    public:
        rectangle(int a, int b)
        {
            a=length;
            b=width;
        }
         int getl()
        {
            return length;
        }
         int getw()
        {
            return width;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int l,w;
    cout<<"enter the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin>>l;
    cout<<"enter the width of the rectangle: ";
    cin>>w;
    rectangle one(l,w);
    cout<<"length: "<<one.getl()<<endl;
    cout<<"width: "<<one.getw()<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you assign values, the one on the right gets assigned to the one on the left.

Comment: `a=length;` -> `length=a;`

Answer (score 1):

In this constructor:

```cpp
        rectangle(int a, int b)
        {
            a=length;
            b=width;
        }
```

You are overwriting the arguments with the meaningless values of uninitialized member varables.

You may want:

```cpp
        rectangle(int a, int b)
        {
            length=a;
            width=b;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you're assigning values to the paremeters `a` and `b` instead of the data members `length` and `width`.

To **solve** this you should initialize the data members `length` and `width` instead of assigning values to the parameters `a` and `b`, which can be done using **constructor initializer list**

```
//use constructor initializer list
rectangle(int a, int b):length(a), width(b)
//----------------------^^^^^^^^---^^^^^^^^--->this is initialization
{
            
}
```

##### Method 2

Note that there is difference between **initialization** and **assignment** in C++. So for example:

```
 rectangle(int a, int b)
 {
//---vvvvvv-------->note length is on the left hand side of assignment
     length = a ;  //this is assignment and not initialization
     width = b  ;  //this is assignment and not initialization
//---^^^^^-------->note width is on the left hand side of assignment
 }
```